# How to pass a json into a select input

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I only know we can have a `each` loop and add `<option ...>` one by one into a `<select>` element.

Is there any binding like `$('select#name').val(data)`?

Comment: you want to bind to a select using a single function call, is that what you are trying to say ?

Comment: Does the data in your JSON structure contain information about the option fields you are trying to add/modify? Or are you just trying to attach the JSON string as the value for one of the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have any methods for this by default. Either you can use a plugin like the one given below

http://www.rvdevsign.net/ressources/javascript/documentation-jquery-jselect.html

Or pass options string `<option>abc</option><option>def</option>` from server-side code and append it to select element using `$('select#name').html(response)`.

I would suggest you not to hesitate to write loop for this as a loop is required somewhere even if you use any of the methods mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

No, `val` simply sets the selected value of a `select`. You can, however, build all your options in a string, and inject them into your select using `html`:

```
$('select#name').html(`<option>1</option><option>2</option>`);
```